# Rules Engine with Constantly Changing Rules

Tags: business-rules

Is there a rules engine that can handle constantly changing rules? The scope of the rules is well defined, but users have the ability to change parameters of rules within that scope whenever they choose to. I don't expect to have more than a couple thousand rules, but they will likely experience numerous changes each time a user joins the system. Should I scrap the Rules Engine idea altogether here or does something exist that meets these demands? I wasn't able to find anything online except an IEEE paper.

Comment: A series of data moves through the system, and these data may fire events given certain criteria. The scope of these criteria is pre-defined and limited, but each user can chose, or edit, exactly what the current set of criteria is that could cause an event to be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Any business rule engine is nominally designed to handle this use case.  However, you will find that they all have different takes on what is important and the technology stacks will be different.  The above answers for InRule and CodeEffects seem good for environments where .Net is required.

Based on statements in your question, it seems that you are going to have a lot of churn in the rules.  I think it is important for you to consider then who will be making these changes and what the governance of the changes will be.  These considerations may be more important to you than the technology platform (.net / java / hosted) or the initial implementation effort, actually.  Most rule projects should be considered with the on-going maintenance in mind more than the initial development.